# Recompiling TeeChart 7 for XE2

Tags: delphi, teechart

I used TeeChart version 7 for an older Dev Studio 2006/C++ Builder project that I intend to update to XE2.  However, I'm using some features of TeeChart that require the paid version, so I can't just use the built-in TeeChart that comes with XE2.

Since I am a TeeChart version 7 source code customer, I assume I can re-compile the packages and re-install them into XE2.  I would like to try to do this to avoid purchasing a new license for Teechart since the newer versions don't really have any additional features I need.  The customized recompiler/installer from Steema for the TeeChart version I have won't work with XE2, so I'll have to do it all manually.

On first try on recompiling the older TeeChart source code, I've got quite a few syntax errors that seem easy to fix, but I don't know how far I'll get before I run into a wall.  But so far, they are all looking pretty straight forward.

Has anyone sucessfully compiled a version of TeeChart this vintage and installed it into XE2?  I want to have some confidence this will work after I spend the time to learn a little Delphi and get the components re-built and installed.

Comment: Have you read the usual reference information on porting (When to change PChar to PAnsiChar and when not to, and all that)? Besides the Unicode changes, you need to deal with NativeInt versus Cardinal changes in Win API declarations, but they're all pretty easy.

Comment: @Warren - I haven't, but I will now :-).  I'll get on this over the next couple of nights and let ya'll know how it goes.  A great opportunity for me to re-learn Pascal and Delphi and learn how to uninstall/install components.

Comment: @warren the TeeChart codebase doesn't do anything funky with strings and so porting is pretty much a re-compile.

Comment: Excellent. Then I suspect it will be dead easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we ported from D6 to D2010, a couple of years back, we just recompiled our TeeChart version 3 code. There were only a handful of very minor issues to deal with. Now, we are just using a very small subset of TeeChart (about 7 or 8 core units) but these are the primary units all the same. I think you have little to worry about.

I eventually did upgrade TeeChart. If I recall correctly it was better support for XP themes that forced us to upgrade from version 3 TeeChart. However, since your TeeChart already has themes support I fully expect a recompile to be successful.

Comment: Sounds very encouraging.  I'll continue to try to get a clean compile and install let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have to disagree, as the TeeChart in XE2 has a much more sophisticated look and additional properties for controlling the look and feel of it (and maybe more). We wound up simply uninstalling the distributed version and installing the new paid version additionally - no need to *replace* the original installation.

Comment: @Jerry What part of my answer are you disagreeing with? Dean is not asking whether or not the modern TeeChart versions are better or not. He is simply asking whether or not it is feasible to recompile pre-Unicode code in XE2. Your comment would better be addressed to Dean than to me. I simply answered the question that was asked.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're recommending to ignore the new version and just use the code of the old version. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jerry I am not recommending that. I am making no comment whatsoever of that nature. Which part of my answer says anything like that. I am answering the question as asked.

Comment: I had things misunderstood, my mistake.

Comment: I'll take a closer look at the newer version of TeeChart that is included in XE2 and see if there's any compelling reason to upgrade to a new license.  It is my hope that the older version will work if the VCL hasn't changed *that* much.  I've got the source code, so I should be able to get it to work.  It's not that old a VCL codebase (2006).  If not, it tells me VCL component developers have a lot of work on their hands between Delphi releases!  And I don't really want to shell out several hundred dollars right now if I don't have to. (I'm using several features not in the base version).

Answer (score 0):

I've counted about 85 {$IFDEF D16} in the actual TeeChart sources.

And this was only the job to adapt the TeeChart 2011 version that already worked with XE. The jump you'd like to do, from TeeChart 7 is quite higher than that (note that the latest IDE supported by TeeChart v7 is D2007, so there are also the changes to make it work with D2009, C2010 and XE to consider, as most of them are accumulative).

I don't want to discourage you, but I don't think it will compile "as-is".

Comment: I'll continue to give it a try.  Most stuff seems to be pretty straight forward so far.  If it's that difficult to do it tells me to forget about continuing to try to use Delphi/C++ Builder and the VCL source code buy was a waste of money. (I've had no reason to try to recompile the TeeChart source until this move from DS2006 to XE2).  A VCL source code base that's a few years old should port pretty quickly, IMHO. I'm still evaluating XE2 and if it takes more that a couple of days, I'll just move on to a VS solution where the libraries work from release to release without this hassle.

Comment: @Yeray It was pretty much a trivial recompile for me from my version 3 TeeChart up to D2010. Admittedly I'm only really using the 5 or 6 core units and no design time stuff.

Comment: FYI, I count 70 {$IFDEF D12}, 16 {$IFDEF D14} and 111 {$IFDEF D15} in the actual sources. Of course this is to adapt the whole package.